# Sanity check on characterization of epimorphisms on Lemma 04VN on Stacks Project.

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

This is part of [lemma 04VN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VN). Given a morphism $R\to S$ of commutative, unital rings $R$ and $S$, the following are equivalent:

1. $R\to S$ is an epimorphism in the category of commutative unital rings
2. The two ring maps $S\to S\otimes_R S$ are equal
3. either of the two ring maps $S\to S\otimes_R S$ is an isomorphism
4. the ring map $S\otimes_R S\to S$ is an isomorphism.

The proof is omitted, but I've been able to see that $1\Rightarrow 2\Leftrightarrow 3\Leftrightarrow 4$.

In showing $2\Rightarrow 1$, I assume the ring maps $\iota_1\colon S\to S\otimes_R S$ defined by $\iota_1(s)=s\otimes 1$ and $\iota_2$ defined as $\iota_2(s)=1\otimes s$ are equal. Since everything is commutative, $(S\otimes_R S,\iota_1,\iota_2)$ is a coproduct in the category of $R$-algebras, if given two parallel arrows $g,h\colon S\to T$, we actually find $g=h$ immediately since $\iota_1=\iota_2$. This shows that $f$ is automatically an epimorphism.

Is this a correct argument? It seems like it proves a property about $S$ that is too strong, and my concern is it is not really correct that $T$ can be thought of as an $R$-algebra to appeal to a coproduct argument, and maybe it is not right to move into the category of $R$-algebras to prove something in the category of commutative rings.

Otherwise, assuming (2), and considering a situation where $gf=hf$, it seems one can define a map $\alpha\colon S\otimes_R S\to T$ by $\alpha(s_1\otimes_R s_2)=g(s_1)h(s_2)$, and this depends on $gf=hf$ to make sense. And then $g=\alpha\iota_1=\alpha\iota_2=h$, proving $f$ is an epi. Is perhaps this argument correct?

Comment: What is the property about $S$ that it proves and that is toot strong?

Comment: All of these properties are equivalent in any category once you said that $S ⊗_R S$ is the pushout of two copies of $S$ amalgamated by $R$, I think what you said is correct.

Comment: @Idéophage That $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{CRing}}(S,T)$ is either empty, or has at most one arrow for any $T$.

Comment: Yes, it is true if you take morphisms *over $R$* (or "under $R$" ; not in commutative rings! in $R$-algebras). This is one way to think about epimorphisms.

Comment: Yes, but my concern is that my first conclusion seems to apply to all morphisms of commutative rings, which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Let $h:R→S$ be the morphism. You still need these two morphisms $f$ and $g$ you are speaking about to be such that $hf = hg$, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: (When you said "given two parallel arrows $f,g$ etc.", you should have said "given two parallel arrows $f,g$ such that $hf = hg$, we have $f=g$" (which is at the same time the definition of the pushout and of $h$ being an epimorphism).)